# Proving Discreteness of the Harmonic numbers

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

For the set $\{1/n\}$ with $n$ in the positive integers, how do I go about proving that the set is discrete?

I have that the distance between two consecutive terms is greater than zero, but does that finish the proof?

Answer (score 1):

If you mean the topological notion of discreteness with respect to the ambient topological space of the real numbers (e.g. [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DiscreteSet.html)), then what you're saying is sort of the gist of it, but you need an additional line or two. We want to show for each $n$ that there is some inverval around $1/n$ which doesn't contain any other $1/m$ for $m\neq n,m\in\mathbb{N}$. Since $1/1 > 1/2 > 1/3 > \ldots$, it suffices to show that we can find an interval around $1/n$ strictly inside $[1/(n+1),1/(n-1)]$, and now that's easy, as you observed that the distance from $1/n$ to each of the endpoints is positive.

Answer (score 0):

You note that there exists a bijection between your set and the set of positive integers (find it). Then, since the set of positive integers is discrete, your set must be discrete as well.

Comment: -1 That is false. The set $\{0\}\cup\{\frac{1}{n}:n\in\mathbb{N}\}$ is not discrete, because $0$ is not an isolated point.

Comment: @almagest we were using a different definition. I was taught that `discrete` means countable. You are using a different definition...